# How to get (Private) IP of EC2 instance in bash script launched by cron?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-ec2

I am currently determining the private IP like so in a bash script that is run via cron `@reboot`:

```
ec2_ip=$(echo $HOSTNAME | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+-[[:digit:]]+' | head -n 1 | tr '-' '.')
```

This works fine but is not very elegant. Is there a simpler way to get the EC2 instance's private IP? And also perhaps its public IP?

Comment: What does `echo $HOSTNAME` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the metadata service for this.

Private ip:

```
ec2_private_ip = $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
```

Public ip:

```
ec2_public_ip = $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
```

Comment: For others wanting the same: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `aws cli` and know the instance-id, you can get the private ip address via:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-02c55bf68498143b3  --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

Or the public ip address via:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-02c55bf68498143b3 --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress' --output text
```

(Although it is arguable as to whether this is any more elegant.)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer did not work for me, because according to the docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html you have to obtain a token first. So I ended up running the following to get my EC2 instance's private address from inside the instance:

```
aws_metadata_token=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
ec2_ip_address=`curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $aws_metadata_token" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
```

Same can be done to get all the other instance info, e.g. the public IP:

```
aws_metadata_token=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"`
ec2_ip_address=`curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $aws_metadata_token" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`
```